# DataOutputStream not generating bytes as output?

Tags: java, file, io

`DataOutputStream` Class is used to write the primitive data types as binary format. I have been using the methods `void writeChars(String s)` of `DataOutputStream` class,to write it in a file using the program...

```
public class FileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String x= "haha";
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("E:/a.txt"));
        out.writeChars(x);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The file a.txt now has the following text as output(all chars separated by space):

```
 h a h a
```

My question is why does the file not having the string as bytes?? 
And please also explain that why there is a need to use PrintWriter when we can use functions of DataOutputStream to write all primitives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataOutputStream` does exactly what it is for. It writes the chars as bytes. One char is made up of two bytes.

So it writes the chars `haha` as bytes

```
0, 104, 0, 97, 0, 104, 0 ,97
```

because char `h` is represented as the two bytes `0, 104`.

When you open the file in your text editor it tries to interprete the bytes according to a specified encoding. Notepad for example will use ANSI by default.

If you open the file in [Notepadd++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) it can shows you the `0` bytes.

[image]

Use an [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) if you want the char to be converted to the byte representation of a defined encoding. E.g.

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
            "C:/Dev/a.txt"), Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
out.write(x);
out.close();
```

This will output the bytes

```
104, 97, 104, 97
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for writeBytes(s) ? 
Or are you wondering why the file doesn't contain something like 1010101010 ?

Comment: yes exactly i m expecting like 10101010 (binary string)

Comment: You wouldn't see that as the text editor would convert the binary to a readable char/string. You can look for some util methods like Integer.toBinaryString(10) which converts int to binary string and then print it to a file.